# Taylor expansion as double linear approximation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, linear-transformations

Starting with the definition of derivative as linear approximation

$f(x + h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + o(h) \\
f'(x+h) = f'(x) + hf''(x) + o(h) \\
h \rightarrow 0 $

is it possible to obtain Taylor's formula

$f'(x + h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + {h^2\over2}f''(x) + o(h^2)$

just mixing up the two above?

And what if f is a multi-variables function? Starting with

$f(x + h) = f(x) + f'(x)(h) + o(||h||) \\
f'(x+h) = f'(x) + f''(x)(h, h) + o(||h||) $

Comment: I think so, but I have not thought too much about it.

Comment: What do you mean by $f'$ and $f''$ for multi-variable functions?

Comment: oh my god this becomes exactly the model i thought about the other day. how fascinating.

Comment: @amd: linear and bilinear transformation